# Dyanmic Linking GLEW and GLFW3 / Distributing OpenGL

Tags: c++, gcc, ld, glfw, glew

I've been trying to dynamically link GLEW and GLFW into some [tutorial code](http://open.gl/drawing) and am running into issues.

First, the design question: what's the right way to do this? If I'm looking to distribute an OpenGL application using GLFW3 in binary and source, what should go along with it and how? I figure a statically linked GLFW and GLEW. But what about GLU, GL, and other future libraries (glm, SOIL, etc)? Mixing and matching static and dynamic must become unsafe at some point, right?

Second, the specific issue I'm facing at present. I've tried every variation I can think of on this simple Makefile, but wound up with some undefined symbols or outright missing libraries every time.

```
BINS           = $(basename $(wildcard *.cpp))
CPP            = g++
CFLAGS        += -fdiagnostics-color -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -static-libstdc++
STATIC_DIRS   := -I./static -L./static
STATIC_LFLAGS := -Wl,--verbose -Wl,-Bstatic -lGLEW -lglfw
DYNA_LFLAGS   := -Wl,-Bdynamic -lrt -lm -lXrandr -lXrender -lXi -lGLU -lm -lGL -lm -lpthread -ldl -ldrm -lXdamage -lXfixes -lX11-xcb -lxcb-glx -lxcb-dri2 -lxcb-dri3 -lxcb-present -lxcb-randr -lxcb-xfixes -lxcb-render -lxcb-shape -lxcb-sync -lxshmfence -lXxf86vm -lXext -lX11 -lpthread -lxcb -lXau -lXdmcp 

all:
    $(MAKE) $(BINS)

%: %.cpp
    $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) $(STATIC_DIRS) $(STATIC_LFLAGS) $(DYNA_LFLAGS) -o $@ $@.cpp

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(BINS) *~
```

This produces undefined references to every GLEW and GLFW function that are called as well as GL functions like `glClear()`. The `$(DYNA_LFLAGS)` variable is what `pkg-config` says GLEW and GLFW3 need to be statically linked, though I'm not sure why standard OpenGL functions aren't able to be called if those LFLAGS actually worked. And last, if I remove the `-static-libstdc++` I get an error from `ld` about `libgcc_s.a` (though `-static-libgcc` also seems to address the issue?).

The directory hierarchy right now is

```
/source.cpp
/Makefile
/static/
/static/libGLEW.a
/static/libglfw3.a
/static/GL/
/static/GL/glew.h
/static/GLFW/
/static/GLFW/glfw3.h
```

Which means `make` can find the libraries and includes. Indeed, `ld` informs:

```
attempt to open ./static/libGLEW.a succeeded
attempt to open ./static/libglfw.a succeeded
```

So what's the issue? And, again, am I even approaching this correctly?

Comment: For undefined reference to GLEW, have you defined GLEW_STATIC before including glew.h in your code?

Comment: Yup. I've also tried it as a compiler directive.